# Can you create inheritance without subtyping using C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, subtyping

Could someone give me an example of inheritance without subtyping and also an example of subtyping without inheritance using C++?

Comment: Can you think of a useful, practical difference between "inheritance" and "subtyping"? I can't.

Comment: No, that's why I am asking @ChristianHackl, thanks anyway

Comment: Did you mean to explore the differences of _dynamic_ and _static_ polymorpism?

Comment: @Wal: But I don't think your question makes sense if you consider these words synonyms. Or did you just mean to ask "Is inheritance and subtyping the same thing"?

Comment: @ChristianHackl I first though the same, but digging a little further made clear that althoug subtyping and inheritance are closely linked, it's not exactly the same thing.

Comment: @ChristianHackl: An example is the square/rectangle-problem. If you want to save storage, you'd inherit a rectangle from a square. But the square is not substitutable by the rectangle.

Answer (score 3):

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtyping), subtyping, is the relation when programme parts written for one type work also for its subtype:

> Subtyping should not be confused with the notion of (class or object)
>   inheritance from object-oriented languages;[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtyping) subtyping is a relation
>   between types (interfaces in object-oriented parlance) whereas
>   inheritance is a relation between implementations stemming from a
>   language feature that allows new objects to be created from existing
>   ones.

So here would be examples of **subtying without inheriance**:

- `typedef int  myint;` creates a perfect subtype  `myint` of `int`.
- `enum mybool { myfalse=0, mytrue=1, mymorethantrue=10 };` creates a subtype `mybool` of `int`.  I can provide `mybool` to any functions expecting an `int`. However, I can't perform some basic operators. So its not a perfect subtype and not the best example.
- In `struct test { unsigned mytmp : 4; };` the member `mytmp` is a perfect subtype of `int`. I can do anything I do with an integer with `mytmp`, but it's limited in values.

With this definition it's also very easy to find example of **inheritance without subtyping**:

```
class Parent {};
class Child :  private Parent {};
```

Here `Child` obviously inherits from `Parent`.  However code written to manage a `Parent` will not work with `Child` (no subsitution possible), because it's privately inherited.

***Remark:*** in practice, many people tend to understand types as classes and subtypes as derived classes. However, it's true that the C++ standard makes a difference between the fundamental types and classes which are viewed as compound types. And enforcement of the [Liskov subsitition principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) requires to think more deeply about these two similar but not identical principles.

Comment: My understanding is that `enum` is a separate type than `int`.  The reason you can pass `mybool` to a function requiring an `int` is that the compiler performs type conversion between `enum` and an `int`.

Comment: found it   [link](http://www.cmi.ac.in/~madhavan/courses/pl2006/lecturenotes/lecture-notes/node28.html)

Comment: @Wal thanks for this reference which is much more concise and precise than wikipedia.  So I can confirm that all my examples except enum (see Thomas' comment) correspond to these definitions.

Comment: Also note, that you can - even though - open your inherited functions to the outside world by using "using". So for this example, you could write class Child : private Parent { using Parent::foo; }